Pass Code to a Method to Access Protected Info
I'd like to write a method that receives code from the caller to extract info from an instance. That method will be called from a few places, so it makes sense to modularise it and write it like this:
private int doSomething(Function<ThisClass, int> getterForInt) {
  int[] exprStart = { -1 };

    SomeClass sc = new SomeClass() {

      @Override
      protected void doInternal() {
        // Here I have access to protected stuff of SomeClass:
        exprStart[0] = this.start;

        // This allows the lambda to access only public stuff of SomeClass:
        exprStart[0] = getterForInt.apply(this);
      }

    };

    // do stuff with sc
    :

    return exprStart[0];
}

Note that SomeClass is a third-party class, so I can't simply modify it.
As lined out above, there are some access restrictions, so this results in a compiler error because start is protected:
doSomething(sc -> sc.start);

Is there a way to allow passing code to doSomething() that can access protected stuff from SomeClass or do I really have to copy/paste doSomething() for every use? I mean I could probably use Reflection and modify the readability (of start in this case), but that's not intuitive.

The problem is not inside doSomething, but inside the method that calls doSomething. If that method was in fact a member of a subclass of SomeClass, then you would be able to access start in the lambda. As a hack, you can create an anonymous subclass with an initializer, which will be executed immediately:
private void myMethod() {
    new SomeClass() {
        {
            doSomething(sc -> sc.start);
        }
    };
}

